# Move TextView according to touch coordinates in android

Tags: android, textview, coordinates, seekbar

In my app, I show the `SeekBar` progress as a `TextView` and X coordinate of the `TextView` should move as user touches somewhere on the `SeekBar`. For that I attached `OnTouchListener` to that `SeekBar` and the logic to change the coordinates of the `TextView` at runtime is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LayoutParams) _currentValue.getLayoutParams();
    lParams.setMargins((int) v.getX(), 0, 0, 0);
    _currentValue.setLayoutParams(lParams);
    return false;
}
```

But the `TextView` stays at that position and does not move.
I even tried with these in `onTouch()` method:

```
    _currentValue.setPadding((int)v.getX(), 0, 0, 0);
    _currentValue.setX((int)v.getX());
    _currentValue.setTranslationX((int)v.getX());
```

But still X coordinate of `TextView` does not match with that of touch coordinates.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: do not return false, return True if you want to control the touches.

Comment: Well, not really. If I return true, the seekbar's thumb won't slide only. As the touch event has been handled. Anyways, I got the answer.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. All I had to do was

```
_currentValue.setPadding((int)event.getX(), 0, 0, 0);

AND NOT

_currentValue.setPadding((int)v.getX(), 0, 0, 0);
```

As v.getX() will not change as "v" is a `SeekBar`. And I am moving its thumb, not the `SeekBar` itself. Silly mistake.